# How to add two data tables of unequal length to plot a curve which should be sum of table1 plus table 2?

Tags: plotting, summation, table

I am facing a problem but Suppose just for an example below, i am mentioning the dummy code of the problem;

```
Tab1 = Table[{x, x^2}, {x, 0.1, 10}];p1 = ListLinePlot[Tab1, Frame -> True]; Tab2 =  Table[{x, x^2 - 3}, {x, 0.25, 12}]; p2 = ListLinePlot[Tab2, Frame -> True, PlotStyle -> Dashed];Tab3 = Join[Tab1, Tab2];
```

so i use the join command, But what i want is sum of these two curves 
as a one curve .

```
p3 = ListLinePlot[Tab3, Frame -> True, PlotStyle -> Directive[Red]]
```

But this gives me two same curves. Anyone here who knows how to handle?

Answer (score 5):

Try `Interpolation`

```
ip1 = Interpolation[Tab1]
ip2 = Interpolation[Tab2]
Show[{Plot[ip1[x] + ip2[x], {x, 0.1, 9.1}], ListPlot[{Tab1, Tab2}]},PlotRange->All]
```

[image]

Comment: thank you ulrich

Comment: You are welcome!